# Update nested property in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue.js application, I have a method to update `src` attribute of the images when a file is selected from a `file` input. This method is being called like this:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png" @change="updateSrc($event, 'profile.photo.path')">
<img :src="profile.photo.path">
```

And I implemented the method like this:

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        profile: {
            photo: {
                path: "images/profile/no-photo.png"
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateSrc: function (event, srcPropertyName) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = readerEvent => {
                srcPropertyName.split(".").reduce((previousValue, currentValue, index, array) => {
                    if (index === array.length - 1) {
                        previousValue[currentValue] = readerEvent.target.result;
                    }

                    return previousValue[currentValue];
                }, this);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        },
    },
});
```

It works great, but I started to think if I really need to use trickery here, like I did with `array.reduce()`. Is there any way to update Vue.js property **by name** when this property is nested? Something like this:

```
app.$set("profile.photo.path", "james.jpg");
```

Which obviously won't work. Is there any straightforward way?

Comment: This is more of a utility feature you're looking for and as such, would not be implemented by Vue. Lodash has this though ~ https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set

Comment: Yeah, I know Loadash. I'm curious if it's doable in pure Vue.js, as it works with reactive data heavily. I understand your point though.

Comment: That's the thing with Vue. It doesn't aim to do everything, just what it's designed to do.

Comment: I am confused by your question! why not do this.profile.photo.path = 'james.jpg'. I apologize if I'm far from the subject

Comment: Because I have multiple images to update from many different inputs.

Comment: I really don't like the way you are designing your application. It's definitely creative but not how Vue is intended to be used.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev what's not Vue-like here? I use a property for `src` attribute, which is the most Vue-like way available. I would use `v-model` if it worked for files, but it doesn't. It is very Vue friendly, the only trick here is to update a property by name. It's for sure more Vue-like than updating the `src` other way, losing reactivity.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev the only change I could apply would be to use a dynamic property name for `src` in input's attribute instead of a method parameter. But if you know any better way, which in your opinion is on par with Vue's design, let me know.

Comment: @Phil, are you sure it's not possible? Vue.js does it internally for `v-model`, which supports dot notation.

Comment: @RoboRobok I wasn't aware of that. Are you sure? If so, Vue is an open source project so you could go looking for the implementation

Comment: @Phil yes, I'm sure. I'm using `v-model` with dots a lot. It's probably just `eval`-ed, but I will take a look.

Comment: Ah, you're talking about Vue's expression parsing. Yeah, I haven't looked at the implementation details

Comment: What did you think I'm talking about? If it works internally, maybe there's some internal method to use for setting as well, like creating an expression to set a value.

Comment: Well, you're talking about what is probably a very small part of the expression parser. I think it's unlikely the utility will be exposed externally but maybe you'll find it. Good luck

Comment: The "vue-like" approach is to have a separate method for each field and call it to update it, or just update it directly. If you need an algorithm to get to the field you want to modify, it's doesn't feel "vue-like". Just my 2 cents.

Comment: You are wrong. Separate method for same behavior is not Vue way to do it and it’s bad practice in general. Have you ever heard of DRY?

Comment: Why not just split the path into two arguments, suitable for use with `$set`? `updateSrc($event, profile.photo, 'path')`

Comment: @RoyJ Because that makes the API ugly and unintuitive. It will work obviously and in practice is probably good enough, but still it's worth asking if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You've created what might be considered a utility function to add behavior to a basic element. But it's not a utility function, because it can only apply to that basic element type. You have, conceptually, a widget: an element extended to have custom behavior that you're going to use repeatedly. The right thing to do is to make a component. Then you can `v-model` the source name or `.sync` a custom attribute name.

The `img` could be included in the widget template or not. It is not clear whether it should, in your case.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    profile: {
      photo: {
        path: "images/profile/no-photo.png"
      },
    }
  },
  components: {
    readerThing: {
      template: '#reader-thing-template',
      props: ['src'],
      methods: {
        updateSrc() {
          const reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = readerEvent => {
            this.$emit('update:src', readerEvent.target.result);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <reader-thing :src.sync="profile.photo.path"></reader-thing>
  <img :src="profile.photo.path">
</div>

<template id="reader-thing-template">
   <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png" @change="updateSrc">
</template>
```

Comment: v-model and @change combined? I don’t like it.

Comment: I don't like it, because it's a wrong use of `v-model`. It would be better to introduce custom attribute instead, not so confusing one that doesn't to what it's expected to do. Isn't there any way to create custom `v-model` implementation that would actually work as the built-in one? That is, for `file` input it would just update the property on file change.

Comment: Please just remember I'm curious here. I'm fine with my own solution, I like mine better than your one actually. But if we can think of something better than both, I'm all in.

Comment: It's not a wrong use of v-model, it's exactly what v-model is supposed to do: two-way binding of a `value` parameter. If you want a custom attribute, you can use one, use the [`.sync` modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier), and `emit` a labeled `update` event. That's a pretty small stylistic quibble.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I thought you are using an additional attribute. It's fine then, but I'd prefer to keep it on `<input type="file">`, not custom template.

Comment: See updated answer. If you're opposed to using a component, which requires having a template, you're not going to like Vue very much. It's a pointless preference. It is better to hide implementation details behind abstractions.

Comment: I agree in general, but not in this case. We are only injecting simple behavior, which in my opinion should be implemented in Vue.js itself. I don't see why would I want to obfuscate an input element in my HTML. And hardcoding accepted types to a template doesn't seem like a great idea neither.

Comment: If they need to be parameters, you can make them parameters. None of this is difficult. You're quibbling about a simple component not being simple enough for an operation that requires you to write a messy function, even though the component makes everything simpler.

Comment: Because I don't like to obfuscate HTML when it's not necesssary. I find your template messy.

Comment: If I make a form, I want it to be readable. Template to me is only good if it's more than one HTML element, like a custom group. Otherwise it's confusing to me and I hate overusing templates.

Comment: You have a widget with customized behavior that you plan to use multiple times, but you don't want to abstract it, because you can't tell what a custom-named widget does?

Comment: No, because it's just a simple input file with attached behavior. It's not a widget. If it was, removing the behavior would make it useless and/or not identical to already existing thing. We have different understanding of widgets and templates, so I guess this debate goes to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just do it with a callback, then.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    profile: {
      photo: {
        path: "images/profile/no-photo.png"
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeSrc(event, callback) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = readerEvent => {
        callback(readerEvent.target.result);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png" @change="changeSrc($event, (newValue) => profile.photo.path = newValue)">
  <img :src="profile.photo.path">
</div>
```